# I want the default value of my select tag to be a php session

Tags: php, html

I have a select tag with country codes, I want the default value of the select tag to be fetched from the database(that is to be the previously picked value). The person can change the value by picking another option of the select tag, next time the person log in, the default value of the select tag will be the last picked option. How can I do this with PHP and HTML.

I've tried using attribute

```
<select value="<?php echo $_SESSION['country_code']?">
```

but it's not working.

Comment: great, but no idea how to help you withour code or a question

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow, I added a line of code to my question but I don't why it disappeared.

Comment: <select value="<?php echo $_SESSION['country_code']?">.. I used this but it didnt work

Comment: I've submitted an edit to display your code, you can read about how Stack Overflow's formatting works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You may want to post a bit more of your code, as the line you've included isn't enough to really debug the issue.

Comment: if you put this "<select value="<?php echo $_SESSION['country_code']?"> its wrong, need to be "<select value="<?php echo $_SESSION['country_code']; ?>">" closing the php tag on the end

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your kindness.

Comment: That's not how that works: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Comment: I have problem posting code in stackoverflow, as i was trying to sought that out, I told my boss and he helped me with the solution to mmy question. This is what he did: <pre><select><option value="<?php echo $_SESSION['c_code']?>">+<?php echo $_SESSION['c_code']?></option><option value="1">+1</option>
    <option value="7">+7</option>
    <option value="20">+20</option></select></pre>. The explanation is that: he put the session in the first option of the select tag, since the default value of a select tag is the first option, it will display the session. Thanks to everyone.